# Can a De Sitter universe have a detectable rotation?

Tags: cosmological-constant, de-sitter-spacetime

In De Sitter relativity, the cosmological constant becomes a geometric term with the dimensions of radius, and the universe becomes a pseudo-sphere.

Is it meaningful to speak of intrinsic rotation of this embedded sphere? How would the CMBR look in such universe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De Sitter space has a maximal number of Killing vector fields. If there was a measurable rotation then some of these symmetries would be broken: the universe would no longer be isotropic and so it would no longer be a De Sitter space.

However, I suspect you are interested in a cosmological solutions with rotation and positive cosmological constant (or inflation-like behavior). If so, have a look at a paper:

> Obukhov, Y. N., Chrobok, T., & Scherfner, M. (2002). *Shear-free rotating inflation*. Physical Review D, 66(4), 043518, [doi](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.66.043518), [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0206080).

This is an example of a rotating closed universe cosmological solution with positive cosmological constant or with a scalar field with inflationary potential. The spatial geometry is of Bianchi type IX, so topologically space slices are  hyperspheres $S_3$. According to the paper:

> analysis of the models (1) reveals their several attractive properties: the complete causality (no timelike closed curves), the absence of parallax effects, and the isotropy of the microwave background radiation.

So, no unusual CMBR features.